# Run discord bot/client from another file

Tags: python, discord.py, sanic

How can i have bot code in one file but run the actual bot in another file (not cogs/extensions).
i need to run it in another file because of loop conflicts.

i tried importing client (variable of the bot constructor) and .start() on it  but it didnt work, only the web server started.

example code:

in bot file:

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!")

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Im ready!")
```

in another file (Sanic web app in my case):

```py
from bot_file import client
import discord
from sanic import Sanic

app = Sanic()

app.run()
client.run("token")
```

Comment: What you need to do is run Sanic inside of the bot, or the not inside of sanic. One of them has to be the primary application and will be used to launch the other.

Answer (score -1):

I have cool solution for you
why Don't you make only 1 file that have all the code like this

```
import discord
import requests
import json

client = discord.Client()

def get_quote():
  response = requests.get("https://zenquotes.io/api/random")
  json_data = json.loads(response.text)
  quote = json_data[0]['q'] + " -" + json_data[0]['a']
  return(quote)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
  print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  if message.author == client.user:
    return

  if message.content.startswith('inspire'):
    quote = get_quote()
    await message.channel.send(quote)

client.run('TOKEN')
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).